# scanf is successful but the value stored is not right for some large floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, double, scanf, numeric-limits

Inputting large numbers for the below code results in `scanf` being successful although the value isn't being stored correctly.

```
printf("\nDouble max: %f\n", DBL_MAX);
printf("\nFloat max: %f\n", FLT_MAX);
printf("\nPlease insert root1 data: ");
float input1;
scanResult = scanf("%f", &input1);
printf("\nScan Result is %d\n", scanResult);

double input2;
printf("\nPlease insert root2 data: ");
scanResult = scanf("%lf", &input2);
printf("\nScan Result is %d\n", scanResult);

printf("%f", input1);
printf("%f", input2);
```

Output:

```
Double max: 17976931348623157000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.000000

Float max: 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000

Please insert root1 data: 1872389723948273985723984756982375698374568

Scan Result is 1

Please insert root2 data: 928734812348721834.2348275

Scan Result is 1


1.#INF00

928734812348721790.000000
```

So my questions are:

1. **First scan:** Why does `scanf` still say the scan result is 1, when you can see that the value isn't stored properly?
2. **Second scan:** Why does it do that rounding it does, and how can I fix it?
3. **In general:** We can see, by the number of 0's, that the `DBL_MAX` and `FLT_MAX` are much larger than the input I gave. So why doesn't it store the input correctly?

Comment: You need a better `c` book (or site)

Comment: @KevinDTimm may I understand why?

Comment: +1 for the interesting question about overflow handling by scanf(). It more than offsets your lack of diligence verifying your inputs ;-).

Comment: Because no book or site would instruct you to declare a float variable and they try to use that form of `printf()`.  (Note: you have edited the post and so the categorically wrong version is no longer visible)

Comment: As I wrote earlier, that was copied from a function that casts it from void*.

Comment: There is no mention in the post above of the word `cast` or `void`.  And, if you copied it from somewhere else - that's exactly what I'm talking about - that book or site is worthless. Also, if you don't preface your comment with my name I'm never going to see it. I stumbled back here and saw your response.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I said it in an early comment I deleted. As far as I know, that's the right way casting from void to float/double.

Comment: Note that the C standard (and POSIX) specification for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) says: _… or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the space provided, the behavior is undefined._  Your string 1872389723948273985723984756982375698374568 exceeds the maximum result that can be stored in a `float`; you invoke undefined behaviour and any result you see is OK.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. First scan: Why does `scanf` still say the scan result is 1, when you can see that the value isn't stored properly?

The scan result is 1 because one input item was matched, converted, and assigned.  That is the meaning of `scanf()`'s return value when it is non-negative.

Furthermore, I *do not* see that the value was stored incorrectly.  You provided a digit sequence that, interpreted as a decimal number, is larger than the maximum value that a `float` can represent.  The `scanf()` function converts such inputs to `float` as a number representing the largest `float` "value" the system can represent; on your implementation, that's a `float` positive infinity.

> 2. Second scan: Why does it do that rounding it does, and how can I fix it?

Floating-point numbers have fixed-size representations, as do all of C's built-in data types.  There is therefore a limit to their precision, and there are many numbers within their range that are not exactly representable.  This is the trade-off between floating-point and integer: types of the former kind have wider range and scale, but they are generally inexact.

Your machine very likely uses IEEE-754 binary double precision as its format for `double`.  That format affords 15-16 decimal digits of precision.  You cannot avoid rounding when some inputs are converted to `double` (even if a different representation were used), because the numeric format simply cannot represent the input to its original precision.  The only way read the input via `scanf()` without rounding is to read it as a string instead of as a number.

> 3. In general: We can see, by the number of 0's, that the `DBL_MAX` and `FLT_MAX` are much larger than the input I gave. So why doesn't it store the input correctly?

In addition to the finite precision issue I already discussed, do note that your first input is larger than `FLT_MAX`, yet you try to read it as a `float`.  To the extent that you think that input is in range for the target numeric format, you are mistaken.

Comment: Good information. I actually would have expected scanf() to fail in the case of an overflow; I find [the man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html) lacking with respect to error conditions. The reference to `strtod` is only regarding the format, not the error handling. For example, can I expect scanf() to set `errno`?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, the man page you reference explicitly says, "If a read error occurs the error indicator for the stream is set, `EOF` is returned, and `errno` is set to indicate the error."  It also refers to `fgetc()` and `fgetwc()` for errors that may be set, and specifies some additional ones of its own.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, note that error conditions are explicitly defined only for *read errors*.  `scanf()` does not report an error on matching failures.  Moreover, it cannot report matching failures for out-of-range numeric input, because in the event of matching failure, it is required to leave the entire unmatched input on the stream.  You cannot rely on being able to push back more than one character, so by the time `scanf()` can detect that the input corresponds to an out of range number, it is committed to converting it *somehow*.

Comment: All you say is correct but is formed to a coherent picture by pulling together diverse information bits and background knowledge ("not more than one character can be pushed back"). The man page could (imo: should) simply lay out the behavior in case of numerical overflow, either for each numerical conversion separately or, if that is too redundant, in an extra paragraph. It appears to me as an error category distinct from the others. I also am not convinced that scanf is committed once it started converting the sequence -- I suppose an illegal byte sequence can cause an abort anywhere.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Provided that at least one digit or a `.` followed by one digit has been read, `scanf` is committed to reading the number, and will read up to but not including the first character which could not form part of the number. So "illegal byte sequences" will remain in the input stream and the number preceding them will be consumed and returned.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, my comments about scanf being committed are indeed not specified in the standard (which is a bit more thorough on some of the details than is your man page), but nevertheless true.  I offered it as more of a rationale.  As far as the standard's requirements for the function, `f` conversion specifiers are specified to match sequences of characters having the same form as the subject sequence defined by `strtod()`'s specifications, and such sequences are of *unbounded length*.  Your input therefore matches, notwithstanding how it can then be converted.

Comment: @rici I meant the case that a byte sequence does not represent a character, I suppose in the given codeset. Because no character can be constructed it cannot be determined whether the input sequence ends or not. ( I must assume that this is only possible in multi byte encodings like UTFxx.) The [iconv man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html), third paragraph, elaborates a bit more. In that case `fscanf` indeed *fails*, I suppose with a negative return value, and sets `errno`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, I'm sorry that `fscanf()`'s definition does not suit you.  I'm sure that if you raise your issue with WG14 then they will give it all the consideration it merits.

Comment: <booking ticket to Markham>

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: `fscanf` does not handle wide or multibyte character sequences. There are no invalid `char` values. So that will not happen. `fwscanf` (in `wchar.h`) does handle wide characters, but the description of its parsing action is the same as `scanf`: "An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input wide characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence." So if there were digits before the encoding error, no error will be returned...

Comment: ... If there is a *subsequent* format item, the encoding error will prevent it from being matched: "If the length of the input item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which case it is an input failure."

Comment: So, there is no undefined behavior due to overflow for the OP's code?

Comment: @rici I was just citing the man pages, in particular the canonical one of the opengroup; but the Linux man page has the same error and description. I can only assume that multibyte is what they mean, in particular because the `iconv` man page describes the same error with similar wording. For single-byte characters you are correct.

Comment: @CoolGuy *That* is an interesting statement, and would indeed be another unexpected consequence of the definition of what scanf does.

Comment: @rici Ah, I found out: EILSEQ is set when the **format** (which according to n1570, but not to the opengroup man page is a multibyte character sequence) contains an invalid byte sequence. While normal conversion specifications are all valid ASCII ("%d" etc.), the "text to match" directive can be multi-byte. E.g. using the format byte sequence `{0xd9, 0xff, '%', 'd'}`, locale "ar_EG.UTF-8", where 0xd9 initiates a 2-byte character sequence but 0xff is an invalid 2nd byte, makes scanf return 0 (because no item was read) *and* set errno to EILSEQ. With input `{0xd9, 0xff, '8', 0}`. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. First scan: Why does `scanf` still say the scan result is 1, when you can see that the value isn't stored properly?

The first number is larger than `FLT_MAX`, so is correctly parsed as infinity.

> 2. Second scan: Why does it do that rounding it does, and how can I fix
>      it?

The second number is smaller than `DBL_MAX`, so it finds the best double precision floating point value for the input number. This is what is displayed. If you don't understand what that means,  [this article will help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

> 3. In general: We can see, by the number of 0's, that the `DBL_MAX` and `FLT_MAX` are much larger than the input I gave. So why doesn't it store the input correctly?

Incorrect. You are parsing the larger number into the double, and the smaller number into the float.